# Why does this dispatch not work?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to wrap my head around using a timer with GCD. There is nothing to the app except viewDidLoad:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let delay = 2
            let q = dispatch_queue_create("dispatchQ", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
            let timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, q)
            print("timerSource created")

            dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                UInt64(delay) * UInt64(NSEC_PER_SEC),
                UInt64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            print("timerSource time set")

            dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, { print("tick") })
            print("timerSource event set")

            dispatch_resume(timerSource)
            print("timerSource resumed")
        } 
}
```

I expected "tick" to print in the debug panel every 2 seconds but nothing happens. Here is the complete output:

```
timerSource created
timerSource time set
timerSource event set
timerSource resumed
```

Can someone say why it's not ticking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nothing happens because 'timerSource' gets unallocated at the end of viewDidLoad. When I make it a global it works as expected. And since the declaration of timerSource refers to q, q has to be a global too.

Another tweek is that since the dispatch time is DISPATCH_TIME_NOW the first tick happens immediately which I didn't want, so I have to short cut the first time (thanks Matt).

So the ViewController that works looks like this:

```
import UIKit

let q = dispatch_queue_create("dispatchQ", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
let timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, q)

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let delay = 3
        var firstTime = true

        dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            UInt64(delay) * UInt64(NSEC_PER_SEC),
            UInt64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        print("timerSource time set")

        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource)
            {
                if firstTime {
                    firstTime = false
                    return
                }
                print("tick")
            }
        print("timerSource event set")

        dispatch_resume(timerSource)
        print("timerSource resumed")
    }
}
```